# Azure Media Services v3 Not Compatible with Azure Function

Tags: azure, asp.net-identity, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-media-services

I am trying to recreate this walkthrough

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/stream-files-tutorial-with-api#download-the-sample

as an Azure Function, and it seems there is some incompatibility between the Azure Function SDK and Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory. If you try to create a new `ArmClientCredentials` like so

`ArmClientCredentials credentials = new ArmClientCredentials(config);`

You get an error like so

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory, Version=3.19.4.11002

The particular nuget package is added to the project. Is this something that requires an additional step not shown here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure Function exception could not load ActiveDirectory file or assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50444973/azure-function-exception-could-not-load-activedirectory-file-or-assembly)

Comment: Can be helpfull https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2373

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will see if I can get away with a downgrade and still have the functionality needed for the new Media Services SDK

Comment: Is that executed locally or hosted? There was an issue with the Core Tools using that library in a way which caused a problem, but that shouldn't present when hosted in the cloud. I think that's the issue Jerry's post points to. Downgrading would work there. If this is happening in hosted, Alexey's link would be good to check and leave a reply on. Also, what version of the Functions runtime are you using?

Comment: can you post your `project.json` used by your Azure Function?

Comment: Look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by rolling down the version of the package to 3.14. here is the repo of the solution (using csproj)

https://github.com/isaac2004/AzureMediaServicesDemo

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using Azure Functions using the blob trigger template. Instead of using the latest version of `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` (which is 3.19.4 as of writing) I had to downgrade to the version number that media services package is looking for (indicated in the error).

My project.json that worked for Media Services v2:

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "windowsazure.mediaservices": "4.1.0.1",
        "windowsazure.mediaservices.extensions": "4.1.0.1",
        "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory": "3.13.1",
        "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions": "1.0.2.206221351"
      }
    }
   }
}
```

Kindly check if the setting below works for you and Media Services v3. At the very least, these should be in your `project.json` in Azure Function:

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Media": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory": "3.19.4",
        "WindowsAzure.Storage": "9.1.1"
      }
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: Had to use 3.14 of the AD library, see my answer